# New to coding and my segues won’t work while simulating

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Xcode 11 Swift

I’m new to coding and my segues will not work after a successful build. I get my initial screen followed by the “hello world” screen after and that’s it. I’ve watched every tutorial possible and followed all recommendations and still no luck. Is there something wrong I’m doing?

Comment: Can you share some code? How are you trying to perform the segue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new I'm assuming that you're using Storyboards. You need to add the segue in your storyboard from one View Controller to another, make sure to click on the segue you added (the arrow) and in the identifier field to add a name to this Segue.

Then in the code of your View Controller, you can call the following code at the point where you want to perform this segue

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueName", sender: nil)
```